# How to play all songs except classical and movie soundtrack music using the Music app on an iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, itunes, music, music.app

I have bought a lot of pop music and classical music on the iTunes store. Some classical music album is like $9.99 for 100 songs, and I think I have about 500 of them in total.

When driving a car, I tend to like to listen to some pop or rock, but since there are so many classical songs, they would play often than not.

Is there a way simply to play all songs except classical, or except classicalm, movie soundtrack, and opera songs?  Perhaps by using something in the Music app or by Siri. (I tried "Play rock music" using Siri, and what I got was "Starting Facetime with Rutso, mobile" and immediate calling at 6am in the morning.)

Playlists shouldn't be used, because if I set up a playlist for current pop and rock music, and then if 15 other songs are purchased later, the playlist will again need to be updated constantly.  Besides, it is a lot of routine work to add 200 rock and pop songs to a playlist.

The iOS version I have is 10.0.2.

Comment: Perhaps you can use smart playlists to distinguish music by genre.

Comment: Sort music by genre and utilize playlists. Categorizing 500 songs can be done in one minute. Eliminating distractions while driving. That one minute sacrifice, might have saved a life.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an app like [SmartPlaylist](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/smartplaylist/id326071802?mt=8) to create smart playlists on your device.

You can also create a smart playlist on a computer in iTunes then sync it to your phone. Even though you can't create smart playlists on the device, they do still update automatically as new music is added to the device. No manual maintenance is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Open the Music app, make a new playlist, put in all genres except classical.

Comment: OP specifically states they don't want to have to continually add music to a playlist as they add more.

Comment: @LexS I don't think you can add Genre to a playlist (as in Music app on iOS 10.0.2). You have to choose Genre, and then it will drill down to a particular song or album, and then you can add it song by song or all songs in album